# HTML 5 - JS - Saving all clicked HREF Targets in an array. Backward/Forward button

Tags: javascript, html, jquery

i'm working on a school project, but i'm having some problems on catching and using clicked link.
In few words i have to create a Backward and forward button.
I've wrote this code

```
var arrayWithElements;

window.onclick = function() {arrayWithElements.push(e.target);};

function Back()
{   
     *I need to print the last catched target on a div named MidPart*   
}
```

i cannot use normal back/next functions, i have to create them using arrays.

Thanks to everyone who answer. :)